# How to Filter a QAbstractTableModel model

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel, qabstracttablemodel

I have created a QAbstractTableModel model called tableModel and QAbstractListModel model called listModel andi have set these model to respective views (QTableView and QListView).I want to filter the tableModel based on the listModel.That mean when someone clicks on a listitem and the tableview should be filtered based on the list item.These models are working perfectly.Please help on how i can do the filtering.

In QSqlModel we can use setFilter member with sql relationship to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [QAbstractProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html#details) to act as an intermediary between the tableview and the table model.  So when an item is clicked on in the listmodel, notify the table proxy to filter all out the unnecessary items from tablemodel for when the table view queries them.

Comment: Do you have any example on how i can use it...I was reading on QAbstractProxyModel and  QSortFilterProxyModel ...any sample code...thankz

Comment: Not personally, I've only used it in a circumstance too simple to be reflective of what you need.  But there's bound to be some somewhere on the web, what your asking isn't unreasonable.